# Is there any way to get OS X to keep the iOS Simulator icon in the dock across Xcode upgrades?

Tags: macos, xcode, dock, xcode-simulator

I use the iOS Simulator often to check webpages so I run it and pick "Keep in Dock". That's works except every time Xcode upgrades it's no longer in the dock and I have to go digging for it again.

Is there any way to keep it in the dock permanently across Xcode upgrades?

Answer (score 1):

[SimPholders2](http://simpholders.com/) looks like what you want, can't prove it until next Xcode update, though.

Comment: SimPholders2 is a menu extra.  It has nothing to do with Dock.

Answer (score 0):

**Command Space** to launch Spotlight
type **Simulator**
now simulator opens up...
see the dock for Simulator icon, 
Control Click on that Simulator icon, 
Options > Keep in Dock

now Simulator stays in the dock for quick access...

Answer (score -1):

Launch the iOS Simulator.app

Right click on it (or control click it) and select 'Options -> Keep In Dock'

That is a Dock-level preference and will survive Xcode updates.  You can see the data set in the com.apple.dock preference domain:

```
defaults read com.apple.dock
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've done for the last 5 years. It doesn't stick which is what I said in my question

Comment: Well that's exactly what I've done for longer than that, and it's never disappeared from the dock.

Comment: I wonder what's different about my machine. I just lost it again. Restarted my Mac [my dock now looks like this](http://imgur.com/Hahyy3R) the iOS Simulator has disappeared yet again

Comment: The setting for keeping something in dock is set in Dock's preferences.  Inspect the output of 'defaults read com.apple.dock persistent-apps'

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking for. It wasn't in there at this point. Adding it back to the dock (run it, lock click icon dock, pick "Options->Keep In Dock") like I always do [added it back](http://pastebin.com/b9aUELmU). Looking at what it added these 3 entries are different `"file-mod-date" = 0;
            "file-type" = 1;
            "parent-mod-date" = 0;` Otherwise no idea what's special about iOS Simulator except it's buried inside XCode instead of like a normal app. You can see Chrome and VLC survived from the pic